# how can I stream a specific user's tweets and return them as a variable

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

Im trying to stream specific user's tweets and return them as a variable for an event based trigger afterwards. I am using the following code, but it does not seem to return any tweets for me.
I am interested in their tweets only and not retweets and want to skip tweets not posted by the specified user.

Any idea where I am going wrong:

```
import tweepy

#API login for Twitter
consumer_key= CONSUMER_KEY
consumer_secret= CONSUMER_SECRET
access_key= ACCESS_TOKEN
access_secret= ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if status.user.id_str != '111111111':
            return
        tweet = status.text
        return tweet

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# initialize stream
streamListener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=streamListener)
stream.filter(follow=['111111111'])

print(tweet)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to stream specific user's tweets:

```
import tweepy
import sys


#API login for Twitter
consumer_key= CONSUMER_KEY
consumer_secret= CONSUMER_SECRET
access_key= ACCESS_TOKEN
access_secret= ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

# StreamListener class inherits from tweepy.StreamListener and overrides on_status/on_error methods.
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if status.user.id_str != '11111111': 
            return
        text = status.text
        print(text)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print("Encountered streaming error (", status_code, ")")
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # complete authorization and initialize API endpoint
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # initialize stream
    streamListener = StreamListener()
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=streamListener,tweet_mode='extended')
    stream.filter(follow=['11111111'])
```